# Are there any patterns for implementing mutable and immutable versions of a holder object?

Tags: java, design-patterns, immutability

In my application I have few types of *holder* objects, which primary purpose is to store heterogeneous related data. Their lifecycles can be divided into two parts:

1. Collecting data as soon as it becomes available;
2. Providing read-only access to stored data for the rest of a holder's life.

It is very tempting to make the holders immutable, but the data is not available at one time to be passed to a constructor. The simplest workaround I see is to make two versions of a holder class, one being mutable, and another being not:

```
public class MutableHolder {
    public int field1;
    public String field2;
    // ...
    public Object fieldN;
}

public class Holder {
    public final int field1;
    public final String field2;
    // ...
    public final Object fieldN;

    public Holder(MutableHolder mutableHolder) {
        this.field1 = mutableHolder.field1;
        this.field2 = mutableHolder.field2;
        // ...
        this.fieldN = mutableHolder.fieldN;
    }
}
```

However, I feel that this approach is violating the DRY principle (I must not forget to update both classes' fields as well as the constructor if I want to change anything) and is error prone. So here is my question: are there any existing patterns that I'm not aware of for implementing both mutable and immutable versions of a holder object?

#### Edit

I've suddenly found out that the code above is a very barebone version of the Builder pattern (see [this](http://cantina.co/immutable-objects-and-the-builder-pattern/) or [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/immutability-with-builder-design-pattern)). This makes me think that in this case DRY violation is considered acceptable.

Comment: In my opinion, you asked the wrong question. Your problem is your data not being available at a point you need it at.
You might need to restructure the code to allow for Object creation?

Comment: @bwa Unfortunately, I can't see a way to make this possible. The data is obtained by parsing a web page with streaming parser - TagSoup. It does not build DOM so I cannot access the whole page in one place, instead, it invokes callbacks once it finds an opening tag or a closing tag or a character sequence.

Comment: Well if you can't make your object immutable, you can't make it immutable. There's no need for two versions. Just make it mutable an be careful to fill in all data you need as soon as you can.

Making objects immutable should help you make your code better - no point in trying if it is too much work or makes the code more complicated in the process.

Comment: @bwa Good point, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have been stumbling over this for a while. Here is a design pattern I have come up with that I have not seen elsewhere.

```
public class Bob
{
    // member variables
    private int value;

    // simple constructor
    private Bob()
    {
        value(0);
    }

    // constructor with value
    private Bob(int value)
    {
        value(value);
    }

    // get value
    public final int value()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    // set value
    private final void value(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }


    // mutable class modifies base class
    public static class Mutable extends Bob
    {
        // simple constructor
        private Mutable()
        {
            super();
        }

        // constructor with value
        private Mutable(int value)
        {
            super(value);
        }

        // set value
        public final void value(int value)
        {
            super.value(value);
        }
    }


    // factory creator for immutable
    public static final Bob immutable(int value)
    {
        return new Bob(value);
    }

    // factory creator for mutable
    public static final Mutable mutable()
    {
        return new Mutable();
    }

    // another mutable factory creator
    public static final Mutable mutable(int value)
    {
        return new Mutable(value);
    }
}
```

- The class is not final, subclassing should be safe.
- All of the constructors must be private.
- public accessors should be final.
- private mutators in the base class should be final.
- public mutators in the Mutable class should be final.
- Use factory methods to construct immutable and mutable objects.

This is like the subclass mutable pattern, but since the Mutable class is an inner class, it has access to private fields and methods in the base class, so nothing needs to be protected which could possibly be overridden. The base class is just like a standard mutable class, except the constructors and mutators are private. The mutable subclass is a thin layer (every method is super...) that exposes the mutators.

To create an immutable instance: Bob test1 = Bob.immutable(99); To create a mutable instance: Bob.Mutable test2 = Bob.mutable();

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is the [State design pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1751/state-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial). Since it main concept is altering an object's behavior when its state changes. Also allows an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class.

In your case you can consider the following implementation:

```
//maintains an instance of a ConcreteState subclass that defines the current state
public class Holder {
    //your code
}

//encapsulating the behavior associated with a particular state of the Holder
public abstract class State{
    //your code
}

//implements a behavior associated with a state of Holder
public class MutableHolderState extends State {
    //your code
}

//implements a behavior associated with a state of Holder
public class ImmutableHolderState extends State {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I think that this solution will only make things overcomplicated. At its base it consists of the same two classes as in Builder pattern (actual holder and the temporary builder), and adds extra glue which in my case gives no value.